# R: Loess regression produces a staircase-like graph, rather than being smoothed, after the value 10

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, loess

[image]

What are possible reasons as to why this is happening? It always happens after the value 10.

A subset of the dataset around the area of interest before and after the regression was applied:

- [Before](http://textuploader.com/dorkk)
- [After](http://textuploader.com/dokse)
- [Dataset to reproduce graph](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5xIxW_XyATWODVKOVdNUUhVb2c?usp=sharing)

This is the `ggplot2` call that I am using to generate the graph. The smoothing span used is **0.05**.

```
dat <- read.csv("before_loess.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    smoothed.data <- applyLoessSmooth(dat, 0.05) # dat is the dataset before being smoothed

    scan.plot.data <- melt(smoothed.data, id.vars = "sample.diameters", variable.name = 'series')

    scan.plot <- ggplot(data = scan.plot.data, aes(sample.diameters, value)) +
      geom_line(aes(colour = series)) +
      xlab("Diameters (nm)") +                                                                                                                
      ylab("Concentration (dN#/cm^2)") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Function used to apply the loess filter:

```
applyLoessSmooth <- function(raw.data, smoothing.span) {
  raw.data <- raw.data[complete.cases(raw.data),]

  ## response
  vars <- colnames(raw.data)
  ## covariate
  id <- 1:nrow(raw.data)
  ## define a loess filter function (fitting loess regression line)
  loess.filter <- function (x, given.data, span) loess(formula = as.formula(paste(x, "id", sep = "~")),
                                           data = given.data,
                                           degree = 1,
                                           span = span)$fitted 
  ## apply filter column-by-column
  loess.graph.data <- as.data.frame(lapply(vars, loess.filter, given.data = raw.data, span = smoothing.span),
                           col.names = colnames(raw.data))
  sample.rows <- length(loess.graph.data[1])
  loess.graph.data <- loess.graph.data %>% mutate("sample.diameters" = raw.data$sample.diameters[1:nrow(raw.data)])

    }
```

Comment: your data before and after are completely identical, so there is no smoothing or transformation at all...

Comment: Sorry! I copypasted the wrong dataset. Please check again.

Comment: I also added a link to .csv files for a workable dataset that can be used to reproduce the graph.

Comment: What value are you using for `span`?

Comment: 0.05. I'll add that to the post.

Comment: The dataset `before_loess.csv` has a lot of zeros. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, that should be correct. It's just like that for the first few hundred rows of the dataset. Thanks for checking.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion! I double-checked to make sure - for this sample, that's correct.

Comment: Have you also carefully checked the code in your post ? It has several errors and it works only after corrections.

Comment: @MarcoSandri Could you clarify? I'm having difficulty replicating any errors.

Comment: For example: `applyLoessSmooth` does not return any value

Comment: @MarcoSandri Sorry about all the trouble. I've updated the code, which should work in a standalone R file, assuming that `before_loess.csv` is in the working directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is simply that your data is rounded to three significant figures.  Below 10, the values on your x axis `scan.plot.data$sample.diameters` increase in 0.01 increments, which produces a smooth curve on the chart, but after 10 they increase in 0.1 increments, which shows up as visible steps on the chart.

The second problem is that you should be regressing against the values of `sample.diameters`, rather than against the row numbers `id`.  I think this is causing there to be multiple smoothed values for each distinct value of x - hence the steps.  Here are a couple of suggested small modifications to your function...

```
applyLoessSmooth <- function(raw.data, smoothing.span) {
  raw.data <- raw.data[complete.cases(raw.data),]    
  vars <- colnames(raw.data)
  vars <- vars[vars != "sample.diameters"] #you are regressing against this, so exclude it from vars
  loess.filter <- function (x, given.data, span) loess(
                    formula = as.formula(paste(x, "sample.diameters", sep = "~")), #not 'id'
                    data = given.data,
                    degree = 1,
                    span = span)$fitted 
  loess.graph.data <- as.data.frame(lapply(vars, loess.filter, given.data = raw.data, 
                                           span = smoothing.span),
                                    col.names = vars) #final argument edited
  loess.graph.data$sample.diameters <- raw.data$sample.diameters #simplified
  return(loess.graph.data)      
}
```

All of which seems to do the trick...
[image]

Of course, you could have just done this...

```
dat.melt <- melt(dat, id.vars = "sample.diameters", variable.name = 'series')
ggplot(data = dat.melt, aes(sample.diameters, value, colour=series)) +  
       geom_smooth(method="loess", span=0.05, se=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!